# Isolated scope same in both element and attribute directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How do I setup an element/attribute directive that acts like:

```
<directive value="string"></directive>
```

and

```
<div directive="string"></div>
```

where the string value is the same in the scope?

```
restrict: 'EA',
scope: {
    value: '=' || '=directive' // ???
}
```

I know `ngInclude` does something similar to this with `src=""`

Comment: The same way as [`ngInclude` does it](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.6/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L197). It is PITA to set up `=` binding manually, I cannot recommend to waste time on such things just because it can be done.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I just didn't know if I was missing something that could be easily implemented or not. I'll just save myself the trouble.

Comment: Directives like ngInclude got a history and backward compatibility. When  a new stuff is created, sticking to `E` convention for components and `A` for directives makes developer's life a tad easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngInclude` implement code, and it will work in your case because `attrs['blob']` gives you `String` and your value `typeof` is `String`.
But if your value was `Object` or `Number` you should use `$eval` or `$parse` for converting its value from `String`.

```
scope.value = scope.$eval(attrs.value || attrs.directive);
```

Or simply you can do this:

```
scope: {
    directive: '=?',
    value: '=?'
},
link: function(scope) {
    scope.value = scope.value || scope.directive;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for.